# iredmail httpd default redirecting to domain.com/mail - how to stop

Tags: linux, centos

I have iRedmail installed on my server, it installed apache with it, when pointing to my domain name, it redirects to mydomain.com/mail - which I would like to prevent. The default index.html file had a header refresh to url="mail", I removed this, but still its doing the redirect. What am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, after clearing my cache its now working. So the answer is to remove the meta refresh from the head tag of the default index.html file in /var/www/html

Answer (score 5):

**Delete the /var/www/index.html** (where there is the redirect advice for the browser) **AND**  **clear browser** cache/use another browser (I checked it with iPad and found that Chrome used the cache, where there was the page with redirect advice [http 302]).